# Modify a character before it reaches a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a numeric text box and I want the numpad decimal character mapped to `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` like Excel does.

**Is there a way to modify (substitute) a key before it is interpreted by a `TextBox`?**

My current strategy is this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        int selectionStart = SelectionStart;

        Text = String.Concat(
            Text.Substring(0, selectionStart),
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator,
            Text.Substring(SelectionStart + SelectionLength)
        );

        Select(selectionStart + 1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the entire Text-property, you could set the SelectedText-property to the separator:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    SelectedText = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
}
else base.OnKeyDown(e);
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issues of all the text copying with my approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can catch the WM_CHAR message by overriding WndProc():

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x102 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == '.') {
            m.WParam = (IntPtr)'/';   // test only
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Beware that you've also got a problem with the clipboard (Ctrl+V).  That's message WM_PASTE, 0x302.  A possible workaround is:

```
    if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsText()) {
        var txt = Clipboard.GetText();
        txt = txt.Replace('.', '/');
        this.SelectedText = txt;
        return;                        
    }
```

Comment: Your suggestion has a problem. `WM_CHAR` does not make a distinction between the normal '.' (`Keys.OemPeriod`) and the `Keys.Decimal` key on the numeric keyboard. The `WM_KEYDOWN` has this information, but for some reason, changing the `m.WParam` from `Keys.Decimal` to `Keys.Oemcomma` doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, didn't realize you wanted to make a distinction.  This is harder, WM_KEYDOWN has already generated WM_CHAR before WndProc sees it, its done inside the message loop (TranslateMessage).  Set a bool flag to suppress the conversion.

Comment: The problem I was seeing with my approach is that it generated a slew of messages and text copying. I think the `SelectedText` approach is the closest I can get. Solves other issues too. Thanks though.